# How to pass two same arguments via python subprocess?

Tags: python, django, subprocess, buildbot

I wanted to pass two parameter in the subprocess call... like this...

```
./buildbot sendchange --branch=poky --property=buildname:nice --property=machine:qemux86
```

So I wrote the below program...

```
# property_name = {'key': 'value'}
y = ['--property={}:{}'.format(key, value) for key, value in property_name.items()]
cmd = [
    './buildbot', 'sendchange',
    '--branch={}'.format(
        branch),
    y
]
```

And above command throws error by subprocess!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iaskin/Workspace/latest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/iaskin/Workspace/latest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/iaskin/Workspace/latest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/iaskin/Workspace/latest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 227, in process_exception_by_middleware
    return super(AsgiHandler, self).process_exception_by_middleware(exception, request)
  File "/home/iaskin/Workspace/latest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/iaskin/Workspace/latest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iaskin/Workspace/buildsys/build_app/views.py", line 93, in home
    property_name=property_name
  File "/home/iaskin/Workspace/buildsys/build_app/helper/build_agent.py", line 50, in submit_buildbot
    output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=bb_master_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

So I changed the above code to this

```
y = ['--property={}:{}'.format(key, value) for key, value in property_name.items()]
cmd = [
    './buildbot', 'sendchange', '--master=bsp-buildvm:9999',
    '--branch={}'.format(
        branch),
    "{}".format(' '.join(y))
]
```

And this is I don't want ...

```
./buildbot sendchange --branch=poky "--property=buildname:nice --property=machine:qemux86"
```

So am I doing anything wrong ? Or Is `subprocess` really doesn't allow this then what are the other alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

In parent process save argument as environment variables. Child process can access it.

Comment: Hi... can you explain more! What do I need to change in the code ?

Comment: os.environ['KEY'] = "my-personal-key"  ---  this type of construct will set an environment variable. Child process can inherit those env vars.

Comment: okay after setting the env then how do I change my `cmd` code ?

Comment: Please can you explain clearly in your answer! I'm not getting what you are trying to say..